# Get non free modules OpenCV 2.4.13 Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, opencv, surf

I am having problems with OpenCV as I need to use SURF on my C++ Visual Studio 2015 project but apparently is not part of OpenCV 2.4.13 and needs to be downloaded separately.

What I specifically need is this package:

```
"opencv2/nonfree"
```

I've been looking over the Internet but I could not find anything, just a few tutorials for Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how to add these modules to the Windows version?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You can build OpenCV from source and select that package to build.